# Oracle queries not executing in SSIS, but work in TOAD

Tags: sql, oracle, ssis, toad

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
    employee_id NUMBER,
    first_name VARCHAR2(50),
    last_name VARCHAR2(50),
    hire_date DATE
);
```

I'm encountering an issue with executing Oracle queries within SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS). Here's the problem:

1. I have set up an Oracle connection manager in SSIS, and the connection tests successfully.
2. However, when I try to execute queries within the SSIS package using the OLE DB Source component, the queries do not seem to execute.
3. Interestingly, the same queries execute without any issues in TOAD, so I'm confident that the SQL syntax and connection details are correct.
4. The same query also executes successfully in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) via SSIS.
5. Additionally, when the SSIS package is executed with the Oracle connection, the query seems to keep loading indefinitely without any result.

I have already checked the following:

1. Verified the connection manager settings in SSIS to ensure they match those in TOAD.
2. Tested the connection from the SSIS package, and it connects successfully.
3. Reviewed the SQL query syntax to ensure it is compatible with Oracle.
4. Checked for any error messages in the SSIS package execution log, but none seem to be related to query execution.

I'm unsure why the queries are not executing in SSIS or why they result in indefinite loading. Are there any additional configurations or troubleshooting steps I should consider to resolve this issue?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Hi what is the error that you are getting ?

Comment: Is the create table query part of the actual problem or just showing us an example of a query?

Comment: A query might have a performance issue only when run with different session settings. For example, maybe SSIS uses a different language or date format then TOAD. To verify if it's a query performance issue, run this while SSIS is running: `select sql_id, elapsed_time/1000000 seconds, sql_fulltext, gv$sql.* from gv$sql where users_executing > 0;` If you don't see a relevant query returned, then it's a problem with SSIS instead of Oracle. If it's an Oracle problem, use this SQL to start performance troubleshooting: `select dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor('SQL_ID from above query') from dual;`